# Retina Tablets & iPad Only Media Query

Tags: ios, ipad, css, media-queries

I've been working on this for about a week on and off. I put the following media query in my code and it runs on my iPhone 5s as well. I only want it to work on Retina Tablets & iPad Only

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px)
  and (max-device-width : 1024px),
  and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

      Retina iPad CSS Only

}
```

Some suggested that the it should be this, but I didn't get any better results...

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1536px)
   and (max-device-width : 2048px),
   and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

      Retina iPad CSS Only

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, after posting this and sending out a SOS via Twitter I finally figured it out...

I had to separate the media queries. Not sure if it's the best way but it works!

```
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

       @media (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

           Retina iPad CSS Only

       }

}
```